# cartodb.js highlight the polygons on mouse hover for Google map v3

Tags: google-maps, cartography, carto

We are using cartodb.js with Google map v3. We are trying to highlight the polygons on mouse-hover. Is there a way to highlight the polygon on Google map using cartodb layer?

Answer (score 2):

One of the things you can do is request the geometry from cartoDB as in a geoJSON format  as part of your SQL query:

```
SELECT *,ST_ASGEOJSON(the_geom) AS geometry FROM your_table
```

Google can take the geoJSON and convert it to polylines and polygons each time you mouse over a feature. Here's an example I've done with a polyline.  You could do the same thing with a polygon, but use google.maps.Polygon() instead.

First create your shape (I created a global one so I could edit it easier).

```
var polylineHighlight = new google.maps.Polyline();
var polyOptions = {  
    strokeOpacity: 0.9, 
    strokeWeight: 13,
    visible: false,
    zIndex: 20
};
```

For more information on doing this with a Polygon, check out the Google Maps API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple)

Then this code would be used as part of your cartoDB featureover callback (via http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#create-a-visualization-from-scratch) :

```
.done(function(vis, layers) {
  layers[1].on('featureOver', function(ev, pos, latlng, data) {
     //Parse the geoJSON
     var geometryJSON = $.parseJSON(data.geometry);
     var pathCoordinates = new google.maps.MVCArray();
     var temp = geometryJSON['coordinates'];
     //Step through each coordinate pair
     for (j = 0; j < temp.length; j++){ 
       var latLongArr = geometryJSON['coordinates'][j];
       for(i = 0; i < latLongArr.length; i++) {
         var lon = latLongArr[i][0];
         var lat = latLongArr[i][1];
         //Place each coordinate is put into a LatLng and push that into an array of coordinates.
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
         pathCoordinates.insertAt(i,latlng); 
       }
     }
     // Change polyline location
     var polyOptions = { path: pathCoordinates };
     polylineHighlight.setOptions(polyOptions);
     polylineHighlight.cartodb_id = data.cartodb_id;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to make sure your cartoDB interactivity is turned on.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/544g34Lh/5/